# Don't Display Email Popup If Referral Is Coming From Email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, mailchimp

I am using this popup email signup form from Mailchimp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], 
function(L) { 
L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"1234567890","lid":"1234567890"}) 
})
</script>
```

Is there a way to not show the popup if the referral is coming from email (since they're most likely already signed up), or better yet is there a way to detect it coming from a Mailchimp email?

I've seen this post from mailchimp: https://blog.mailchimp.com/how-we-made-a-non-annoying-popup-form-for-the-thread/ But am not sure how to apply it to what I need.

Any solution using PHP, jQuery, JS would work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a way to know that they're coming from MailChimp? I imagine you have some kind of identifier in the links in the email. If not, you should.